# How can I debug memory alignment problems (AVX) when they don't reproduce in a minimal context?

Tags: c++, debugging, point-cloud-library, memory-alignment, eigen3

I run into the following problem all the time recently:

1. I have a large-ish codebase which uses [Eigen](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/) and [PCL](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/) (which also uses [Eigen](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/))
2. I need to use the almost current Eigen master branch and can't use a stable release due to a dependency requiring it.
3. Both PCL and other dependencies in my project make use of vector instructions, so I compile with `-march=native`.
4. When running some things that involve Eigen types (Affine transforms, Point cloud viewing), I sometimes get segmentation faults or other crashes in seemingly nonsensical locations, such as in the `Eigen::Quaternionf` constructor. In other case, the `EIGEN_UNALIGNED_ASSERT` is triggered, which leads one to [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__Alignement.html), whose contents I observe everywhere in my code (so far as I know)

I want to be a good citizen so I try to reproduce the problem on a minimal example to post on stackoverflow or in the related issue trackers. However I invariably fail at reproducing the crash when extracting just the bit triggering the problem. My guess is that whether or not memory is aligned (and no special care is taken) is also dependent on what was allocated before the problem location, so the surrounding code is instrumental in triggering the issue.

**Question:** What techniques and tools can I use to effectively determine the source of memory-alignment-related crashes in C+14 on Linux and/or macOS?

Comment: Could it be an issue of data alignment? I had that issue before yet I did not get a segmentation fault but an AVX-error directly. Is your data 32 bit aligned?

Comment: i am not sure, how to find that out is part of my question. Assuming PCL has no bugs in this regard I would think so, as i am using only PCL types, but I have the same issue sometimes when manipulating Eigen 3x3 or 4x4 matrices and vectors.

Comment: I would strongly assume that PCL has almost no bugs in it :)

Comment: are you sure you allocate the data correcty?

Comment: I find that these problems (I assume its all the same underlying issue) sometimes manifest in segfaults, EXC_I386_GPFLT errors, or Eigen assertions).

Comment: Well PCL used to and still has probably lots of issues, but for something like this it would be surprising if no one noticed. Since I'm only using PCL type constructors I don't think it's possible to misallocate data.

Comment: Make sure all compilation units are built with the same flags (especially don't mix AVX with no-AVX). If you want to find the source of an error, you could try running your code with valgrind. And if you have trouble creating a [mre] from scratch, try the divide-and-conquer approach (keep removing parts of your code, until no more crashes occur -- then restore those, and remove other parts).

Comment: Do you have core dumps?  That should make it possible to confirm immediately whether alignment is the issue (look at the faulting instruction and its operands). and if so, the stack trace should help determine who created the improperly aligned object.

Comment: Can you expand on that? I can generate core dumps or crash dumps on macos and also look at what is failing in the debugger (latest example is `vmovaps` which seems an avx instruction). but i don't know how to figure out the source of the misalignment.

Comment: Is the misaligned data on the heap or on the stack? The description hints that it is on the stack, so including the call stack and the alignments in it could help nail it down.

Comment: The misaligned data is probably on the stack, since in this case  it occurs in a fixed-size Eigen type, which is why i assume the problem is elsewhere to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend `AddressSanitizer`.
On an embedded application I once had a small stack overflow on a buffer which had side effects only when the stack was nearly full .I finaly found the stack overflow with including this command options on my cmake (works with gcc).Note the `fsanitize=alignment` finds runtime bugs related with alignment ,[gcc documentation about ASan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) says:

> This option enables checking of alignment of pointers when they are dereferenced, or when a reference is bound to insufficiently aligned target, or when a method or constructor is invoked on insufficiently aligned object.

And those are the most probable bugs when you are dealing with custom alignment

```
add_compile_options(
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Og>
    -fdiagnostics-color=always
    -Wuninitialized
    -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=undefined>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=address>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=alignment>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=bounds>
    -fno-sanitize-recover
)
add_link_options(
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=undefined>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=address>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=alignment>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=bounds>
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this relates to alignment problems?

Comment: @oarfish Oops I missed the most important  parameter, i just edited my answer

Comment: With clang, this gives me `clang: error: unsupported argument 'bound' to option 'fsanitize='`. So I guess GCC only.

Comment: With gcc apparently it needs to be `bounds` not `bound`.